# get files modified by me in a branch after merging some other branch into it

Tags: git, github, merge

Suppose I have branch called `a`. I have committed some changes to it.

changes in commit.

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Now I have merged some other branch called `master` in my branch `a`.

And there are some other files added to to my branch `a`.

changes merged as,

```
10.txt
11.txt
12.txt
```

Now branch `a` can have all the changes.

I want names of files which are modified by myself.

So tried,

```
git checkout a
git diff --name-only master
```

But this gives all the files which are modified or added by myself + others.

I looking for only files modified by me.

Any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
git log --name-status --oneline --author='Your Name'
```

And if you need to only see what changed since your merge commit, look for the merge in your git log and filter by that revision.

```
git log --name-status --oneline --author='Your Name' <your_commit_hash>..HEAD
```

The key is the `--author` flag.

**Edit:**

There is going to be some other output, like your commit hash and message. `git diff` does allow you to only show the filesname, but it doesn't allow you to filter by author yet. So you might have to do this programmatically if you want to just output filenames and filter by author.

Comment: git log does give file names. What are you talking about?

Comment: I meant unique file names. This will give commit messages etc as well, and if a file was altered and committed multiple times, then that would also add some noise.